# Error with new QGIS version no attribute 'isatty'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-3

I have a make QGIS plugin it work on QGIS 3.10

But when I try to make it work on QGIS 3.14 + I dot some error

I have install QGIS 3.22.5 and I have see few error:

- pip install pythonnet have to be change by pip install --pre pythonnet for compatibility with python 3.9
- clr is not in python I have to use python3 -m pip install clr

but when I launch QGIS I still have

[image: Crash report by QGIS]

I dont know what to do with that, is clr not supported anymore ?

Comment: Something has set `sys.stdout` to `None` (assuming it wasn't that in the first place). What is `sys.stdout` in the QGIS Python Console?

Comment: You say "I have a make QGIS plugin it work on QGIS 3.10" but do you mean "Python 3.10"?

Comment: it was a stupide problem , pythonnet donsent work on python 3.9 si i use pip install clr 
and then instal pre pythonnet to have a good version of pythonnet 
but the CLR import make it does'nt work 
i uninstal CLR and now its work

Answer (score 0):

pip install --pre pythonnet is the way to make it work
but installing CLR make it fail
so juste uninstal CLR and it work